# Change constraints based on device during run time

Tags: ios, storyboard, constraints, autolayout

I'm using Storyboard to set my constraints. While everything is perfect, I have a some views where I wish to change the constraints on only 3.5" devices.

Is this possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a macro to determine the screen size, like the following:

```
#define isiPhone4 ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480)?TRUE:FALSE
```

Later in the code you can do something like this:

```
if (isiPhone4) {
    self.constraint.constant = NEW_VALUE;
}
```

To access storyboard constraints from code you should make `IBOutlets` for them (control+drag them into your controller like anything else).

[image]

Comment: I was hoping the storyboard to be able to activate/deactivate autolayout on individual scene. But guess that will have to wait for future releases of xcode.