# Constraints not working when Resizing UIView via Animation

Tags: ios, iphone, constraints, autolayout, uiviewanimation

It's kind the weird I'm facing right now, I know that adding constraints in an AutoLayout IB is simple. But I really couldn't figure-out why my simple constraints are not working when I'm resizing (ZoomIn Animation) a UIView.

The View I'm targeting to zoomIn works fine, but the subviews within it is not being positioned well. It seems that the constraints are not working.

From this setup, where in the Yellow Boxes are UIViews and the Green Boxes are UIImageViews.
When I tapped on a Yellow Box, it should zoomIn, as what is shown on the photo below it.

[image]

These are the constraints:
[image]

This should be the expected resulting upon zoomIn AnimationBut I got no luck, The yellow box zoomIn but the Green Box is let on its old position and did not changed size.

I put a leading, trailing, topSpace, and bottomSpace from Yellow Box to Green Box already.
My code for resizing the yellow box is:

```
- (void) resizeViewWithZoomInAnimation: (UIView*)view duration:(float)secs option:(UIViewAnimationOptions) option {

//sets the new width and height of deal's view
float newWidth = view.superview.frame.size.width - 20;
float newHeight = view.superview.frame.size.height - 20;

[UIView animateWithDuration:secs delay:0.0 options:option
                 animations: ^{

                     switch ([view tag]) {
                         case 1:
                             [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, newWidth, newHeight)];
                             break;
                         case 2:
                             [view setFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(view.frame),CGRectGetMinY(view.frame), -newWidth , newHeight)];
                             break;
                         case 3:
                             [view setFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(view.frame),CGRectGetMaxY(view.frame), newWidth , -newHeight)];
                             break;
                         case 4:
                             [view setFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(view.frame),CGRectGetMaxY(view.frame), -newWidth, -newHeight)];
                             break;
                     }
                 }
                 completion:nil];
}
```

This should be the expected resulting upon zoomIn Animation:
[image]

Comment: How do you know it isn't working? If you resize a UIImageView, it does not necessarily resize the _image_ displayed by the UIImageView. So perhaps the image view is being resized as you expect. One way to find out: give the image view a background color so you can see where it really is, independently of the image it contains.

Comment: However, if the UIImageView really _isn't_ being resized as its superview is resized, then yes, there is something wrong with your constraints.

Comment: The reason why I put a green background color is for me to test if it's working fine. The thing is, what ever the constraints I put, it's not working. Can you suggest anything? Thanks

Comment: If the green box doesn't move at all, it sounds to me like you made your constraints to the wrong thing (i.e. not to the yellow box that is its superview). Give your views in Interface Builder _useful labels_ so that the constraints clearly tell you what views they are connecting.

Comment: Oh, one more thing. Make sure your view hierarchy is right. The green and yellow boxes should not just be subviews of the main view (siblings): make sure the green boxes are _inside_ the yellow boxes (as subviews of them), not merely in front of them.

Comment: Actually, I already did what you have just stated. That's why it's kind the weird that it's not working. I'm pretty sure with my constraint. Really weird. There's no code involved here right? constraints can achieve my expected result right matt?

Comment: Absolutely. It's totally trivial. This is just the kind of thing constraints are for - to dictate how a subview should compensate when its superview is resized. That is why I suggest maybe you have drawn the constraints between the wrong objects.

Comment: I would like to see what resizeViewWithZoomInAnimation: actually does.

Comment: If ever my constraints are wrong, the green box should atleast move somewhere else. But the weird thing is it's really on its old position. I tried putting labels and buttons with their own constraints (center horizontal) but they are not also being positioned well. Constraints not working at all! Sad :-(

Comment: Well, it is odd. But you're not showing your code and you're not showing your constraints, so it's impossible to help you except by sheer guesswork (which I've already tried).

Comment: Hey Matt and Bilobatum, I edited my question, attached there is the screen shot of the constraint and the code for my resizeViewWithZoomInAnimation: ... So what can you say guys?Thanks

Comment: directly changing the frame will not affect autolayout properly. You have to change the constrains values of particular view

Answer (score 15):

When trying to animate with Auto Layout, you should **not** change view's frames directly. Instead, you should animate changes in constraints.

*To access constraints from storyboard you can simply [create IBOutlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748156/change-constraints-based-on-device-during-run-time/21748704#21748704) for them.*

```
[containerView layoutIfNeeded]; // complete pending layout operations (optional)
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{

    // Update constraints
    self.viewConstraint1.constant = NEW_VALUE;
    self.viewConstraint2.constant = NEW_VALUE;

    // Animate the changes
    [containerView layoutIfNeeded]; 
}];
```

*Note that you usually want to call layoutIfNeeded on the super view(or higher) of the view you are trying to animate.*

I recommend reading more on Auto Layout in Apple's [official guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH7-SW1).

Comment: Switched my code over to work this way, works well for resizing, but so far calling [UIView animateWithDuration:secs delay:0.0 options:option
             animations: ^{
                 [myView setNeedsLayout]; // animate change in constraints
             }
             completion:nil];  does not cause any animation.

Answer (score 2):

A tweak to the above answer,  I used from within a UIViewController

```
  [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
  [UIView animateWithDuration:.5
                         animations:^{
                             myConstraint.constant = 64;
                             [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             // whatever
                         }];
```

Changes of note: Apple docs recommend using layoutIfNeeded, and calling this both before and within the animation block.  This is so that you can be sure the animation stack is cleared before beginning.

Also, you are to call layoutIfNeeded on the parent view of the constraint you will be animating, not on the view who owns the constraint.  Thanks to @nkukushkin for the initial answer.

It's also important to have your constraints set up correctly.  The 'fix constraints' tool in IB won't necessary set them up in a way that works correctly for animating.  For me I had to go through them and think through how I wanted the dependencies to work, which is of course expected but might not be obvious to the beginner (and results in errors).

Comment: Thanks for explicitly pointing out where to make the layoutIfNeeded call. I had a similar problem and the resize worked fine, but without animation. This fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using constrains, pre-constrains are generated. When you act on position and size, remove constrains while animating the view or do following:

```
yourView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
```